# Keras weights of first layer didn't change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm very new to Keras and I'm writing a custom layer which implements Gaussian function [`exp(-(w*x-mean)^2/sigma^2)` where W, mean, sigma are all randomly generated].
Below is code for the custom layer:

```
class Gaussian(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Gaussian, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create trainable weights for this layer.
        self.W_init = np.random.rand(1,input_shape[1])
        self.W = K.variable(self.W_init, name="W")

        # Create trainable means for this layer.
        self.mean_init = np.random.rand(1,input_shape[1])
        self.mean = K.variable(self.mean_init, name="mean")

        # Create trainable sigmas for this layer.
        self.sigma_init = np.random.rand(1,input_shape[1])
        self.sigma = K.variable(self.sigma_init, name="sigma")

        self.trainable_weights = [self.mean, self.sigma]
        super(Gaussian, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        result = tf.multiply(x, self.W)
        result = tf.subtract(x, self.mean)
        result = tf.multiply(tf.square(result),-1)
        result = tf.divide(result, tf.square(self.sigma))
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

After putting it as the first layer in a [Keras mnist tutorial](https://github.com/wxs/keras-mnist-tutorial/blob/master/MNIST%20in%20Keras.ipynb)(just wanted to make sure it runs without producing errors, didn't care for accuracy) and training the model, it appeared that the loss stopped decreasing after around 4 epochs and only the numbers of "mean" and "sigma" changed after training while the numbers of "W" remains the same. However, this doesn't happen if I put it as the second layer.

I ran the Keras mnist tutorial again without the custom layer and found out that the weights of the first layer didn't change either.

Is not updating the weights of first layer(more specifically the very first parameter) a Keras thing or am I missing something? Can I force it to update?
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like your network might be experiencing the vanishing gradient problem since during the backpropagation phase, the gradients are getting smaller and smaller, so the weight updates become non-existent. Here's a wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) on it.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Thank you! So is it possible to have vanishing problem but still have good accuracy as this seems to be the case with Keras mnist tutorial without the custom layer?

Comment: When you say good accuracy, are you referring to the accuracy on the test dataset? It can have good accuracy on training but bad accuracy on the test, which implies overfit.

Comment: I just thought of something: If the problem is vanishing gradient, shouldn't the weight still change a little bit before it comes to a complete stop of change? Or is the change just too small even for the first back propagation?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you. Basically, the observed behavior is that the weights in your last layers will change, but as your backpropagate towards the first layers, the weights will change less and less, so therefore, by the time you get to your first layer, the gradient is so small that the weights won't change. I'm not too sure how many layers you created, but this problem happens for very deep layers. Also, if you used ReLU as your activation, then I doubt vanishing gradient is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are not implementing your layer correctly, Keras is not aware of your weights, that means they are not being trained by gradient descent. Take a look at [this](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) example:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

Here you have to use `add_weight` to obtain a trainable weight, not just use `K.variable` as you are currently doing. This way your weights will be registered with Keras and they will be trained properly. You should do this for all trainable parameters in your layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this method and the outcome was the same.

Comment: Hello! Your example is helpful. Can you also tell how can we implement an activation like tanh?